# Is there a connection between stress and difficulty in acclimatizing?

Tags: hiking, high-altitude, acclimatization

In the experience of users of this site, does intense stress hamper acclimatization?  I recently experienced much more difficulty in acclimatizing in an area where I frequently visit.  The only difference is that I recently have come under a great deal of stress.

(Please note that I am not asking for opinions, but first-hand experience or close observation; I also know that what is true for A may not be true for B.)

Comment: In my opinion is your statement the perfect explanation why this is not a good question: This is solely opinion based as all first hand experiences in this matter cannot be generally applied. This matter is way too complicated, even in everyday situation implications of stress are not completely known.

Comment: I am asking for data, not opinions.  I am asking for what people have experienced, not what they think.   It may very well be that no one reading this question can make any connection between acclimitization and stress in his or her personal experience.  If so, OK.  In fact, if so, that in itself is data.  As for the fact that implications of stress are not "totally known" .... what is the point in asking a question if everything about the subject is known?

Comment: Sounds like a title for someone's thesis.

Comment: My main point quoted from you is: "I also know that what is true for A may not be true for B" You are asking for personal experiences which will in this case have no general relevance. The second point is a ShemSeger says: The only way to get not opinion based answers is, if there were studies or at least some kind of structured observation on many cases on exactly that subject. But that is an immensely difficult undertaking, which is still worked on in much more general terms than high altitude acclimatization.

Comment: This seems a perfectly valid **question**, whether there is a good **answer** is another thing. Some questions just don't have good answers...yet

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a connection between stress and difficulty in acclimatizing?

No, no **known** connection has been made between stress and acclimatizing at altitude.

Does this mean that stress couldn't make acclimatizing worse? Probably not. It's simply not known what affect this has (It would also be difficult to test)

Acclimatization is an extremely complicated process and is still not well understood.

### My 2 pence worth

Many factors influence how your body acclimatizes. When under stress many things are working extra hard (e.g. [your bodies immune system is weaker](http://www.apa.org/research/action/immune.aspx), etc.). High altitude acclimatization is reliant on pushing your body beyond it's typical operating parameters.

Your body needs to do what it normally does **and** adjust to the lack of oxygen, etc. So I would **guess** that stress will make it harder to acclimatize. It's simply adding an addition burden onto your bodies resources that it could do without.

How big an affect, will vary considerably on the person and about 100 other things :)